# Invoke a function dynamically based on the type of one parameter (was "Zope in Haskell")

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and I find it very elegant and powerful. But I still have trouble imaging how to do things that seem so simple using OOP. Take for example the zope3/grok/pyramid web platforms. They have a beautiful philosophy based on matching content and views to render pages.

In zope, you have a tree of heterodox content types. When you request an URL you use its path to `traverse` that tree and get a `context` object. The last part of the path is the "view name". You get the `View` based on the type of the object and the view name. The `View` is a function from the specific context type and the `Request` to a `Response` object.

So if you visit the url http://example.com/aFolder/aFaq/aQuestion/index.html, zope will start at the root of the tree. It will search for a node named `aFolder`, and then inside this object for another named `aFaq`, and inside it for one named `aQuestion`. So the `traverse` function could return an object of any type.

There's no problem here. Since I'm only traversing the tree I can create a new wrapper type or a class in Haskell named `Traversable`, so I would have a `Tree Traversable` and a function `traverse :: Tree Traversable -> [string] -> Traversable`.

But then comes a problem, `index.html` is the name of a view. In a simplified exposition[*]
Zope looks for the pair (type of context, viewname) and returns a function, roughly speaking, of type `{type of the context} -> Request -> Response`. I could write a function `render :: Traversable -> String -> Response`, that checks the type of the traversable, but then, anytime that someone add a new content type or a new view, that function would have to be updated. The view function (or a sub-function) needs to know the type of the context to use its data.

**So, how a seasoned haskeller attacks this type of problems? For a moment I thought in GADT, but I'm not sure if that will help or if there are more simple alternatives.**

Thanks!

EDIT: Pseudocode to clarify

```
def traverse(node, path):
    # returns the context and the view name
    itemname = path[0]
    if hasattr(node, itemname):
       # The next element in the path is a subnode of the node, let's visit it
       return traverse(node[itemname], path[1:])
    else:
       # We can't go down the tree anymore, we found our context and view name
       viewname = itemname
       return node, viewname

def render(tree, request):
    path = somehow_get_path_from_request(request)
    context, viewname = traverse(tree, path)
    # We get the view from a registry which is a map/dictionary
    view = registry[(context, viewname)]
    # here comes the problem:
    #   view is an object that knows exactly the type of context
    #   A view for a Question object can use its 'question' and 'answer' fields
    #   A View for a Folder can use its 'items' fields, a view for Image can use
    #   its 'img' field.
    #
    return view.render(context, request)
```

This is what I don't know how to do in haskell. In haskell f I have a tree, it must be of homogeneous objects. So I have to define a wrapper type Traversable. But then if someone wants to add a new type he should have to modify my code. Or I could create a haskell class Traversable. In this way an future type could be added to the tree. But then how could I map from (context, viewname) to a function of an unknown context?

[*] The truth is a little bit more complicate. In zope, an object or its class can be marked at runtime with arbitrary `interfaces` (python doesn't have the concept of interfaces, this is a construction entirely of zope). The interfaces form a tree. You associate a view with a pair (interface, name). When you ask for the view of (context, name) it returns the view associated with the most specific interface. The idea is that you could change the view, changing the registry of interfaces and not modifying code.

Comment: So in your heterodox tree, what exactly is contained in it?  A tree of folders and then view-names as leaves?  What's hetero about it?

Comment: The tree is formed by any kind of python classes. Some of these classes are containers, others are only items. Containers could be a Folder, a FAQ, a Blog, a News Folder... The Items could be a File, an Image, a Page, a News Item, a Question...

Comment: A programmer could add its own containers and Items without modifying the previous code. The traverse could end on any step, not necessary a leaf. So we end with a context that could be of any class (A Folder, a Blog, a Page, a Question, something else). The view is determined by the type context and the name that rest in the path. What I find difficult is how to get a function, the View, that act on the specific type of the context, which is unknown at compiler time.

Comment: Well, a problem seems to be that it's not typesafe, as it is now, any wrong data in the registry leads to a run-time type error.  So we either have to prove (using types) that the correct data is in the registry, or reformulate it so that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Exactly! And for a newbie like me, everything looks like it requires side effects or should be type unsafe. So I was hoping that someone came and say "If you make this change, you can get the same effect and keep the type information at the same time".

Comment: Another idea is to uses lenses on the contexts.  I don't know much about lenses though.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding this right, your problem boils down to "I want to stuff things of unknown type into a container, and then at run-time I want to pull them out and run a different function based on their types".

There are a couple of possible ways to attack this problem, with varying degrees of complexity.

First of all, Haskell has *type erasure*. When you compile a program, after the compiler checks that all the types are OK, it *erases* them. So it's impossible, at run-time, to tell what type anything has. This only works because it's impossible, at compile-time, to not know the type of something. This is a verbose way of saying "Haskell is statically-typed".

Having just said that, "Haskell with a few extensions" can be made to do this. However, I suspect that your problem may have a much simpler solution...

OK, so you want to store different types of stuff. But what do you actually want to *do* to this stuff once you've stored it? If you just want to execute some function on the data (depending on its type), then why not *just store the function itself?*

Think about it. Instead of a container with lots of different types inside it, it would simply contain lots of functions with identical types. You fetch the function you want, and you run it. Done.

What's that? You need to be able to run *several* different functions on your data? Well, in that case, try storing a data structure containing all the functions you need.

Comment: I was going to suggest this too.  In particular, instead of creating a context, the routing table calls a handler for an URL, where the handler understands the context implicitly.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but wouldn't this be wasteful? For example, there's only one `addQuestion` view/function for all records of type `FAQ`. So if there are five FAQs in the tree, there should be five copies of the same function. And, if someone decide to add a new view, then he should visit all nodes on the tree and add a copy of the new function on each node of the right type.

Answer (score 2):

So, I think a reified Typeclass might be helpful.  I still don't quite know what you want.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Showable = forall a. (Show a) => Showable a

instance Show Showable where
  show (Showable x) = show x

exampleList = [Showable 42, Showable "have a nice day"]
```

In your case, you need to make a Context type class and then a datatype over it, call it Contextable (horrible name,but I can't think of something better at the time, sorry).
Then you can store a Data.Map from (Contextable, ViewName) to Contextable -> Request -> Response.

Now, if you have a SpecificContext that has some information you need in it's associated view, but none of the other contexts have it, you can do something like

```
class Context a where
    maybeSpecificContext :: a -> MaybeSpecificContext
    ...

instance Context SpecificContext where
    maybeSpecificContext ctx = Just ctx
    ...

instance Context OtherContext where
    maybeSpecificContext _   = Nothing
    ...
```

But I think that looks a little bit ugly.  Perhaps you do this for attributes of a context, so there's less work if things overlap.  But it'll work.

Comment: I follow you up to Data.Map. The problem I see is that the views to be useful must know the type of the context, `Folder -> Request -> Response` or `NewsItem -> Request -> Response`, since the idea of the view is to display content specific to the context. But of course, there's a type mismatch there and that's the part I don't know how to solve.

Comment: If you only had 2 different contexts: `Folder` and `File`, and two functions, one  `Folder -> Answer` and one `File -> Answer`, you could store both in the same type as `(Either Folder File) -> Answer`, where it fails in some way if given the wrong one (either using `error`, or failing nicely by returning a 501 Response or whatever).  You can do the same thing with different contexts.

Comment: Or, since there's a lot of context, to create a wrapper type, Context = CFolder Folder | CFile File | ....  but there are two problems there. One, it's not elegant, and two, if someone wants to add a new type, he should have to modify that function, which won't be correct if we're talking about an extensible framework.

Comment: Logically, we want to unify the contexts with a supertype, but we don't know what the interface should be.  So, we should use a type that is a supertype of all types, Data.Dynamic. http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Dynamic.html